# Chat application using XMPP Server

Tags: blackberry, java-me, xmpp

I am making a chat application using an XMPP server. The chat application works great but I have a problem: when chatting between 2 users, I cannot know if the message from the first user has reached the server or not.

So how to know if a message from a first user reached the server without having to be worried about the second user if he is online or offline.

Please HELP

I am sending the message like this:

```
final SecureConnection sc = (SecureConnection)Connector.open("ssl://...", Connector.READ_WRITE);
is = sc.openInputStream();
os = sc.openOutputStream();
this.reader = new XmlReader(is);
this.writer = new XmlWriter(os);

public boolean sendMessage(final String to, final String msg) {
this.writer.startTag("message"); 
this.writer.attribute("type", "chat"); 
this.writer.attribute("to", to); 
this.writer.startTag("body"); 
this.writer.text(msg); 
this.writer.endTag(); 
this.writer.endTag(); 
this.writer.flush();
}
```

Comment: what is a writer in this method ?

Comment: It is an xml writer to write the data to the XMPP server

Comment: of course that I know , what I want to know is, which class's object/variable it is ?

Comment: okies,well you can use , HttpConnection for it. Or just check whether your SecureConnection has any method like getResponseCode() ?

Answer (score 3):

If you are connected to the server and you send a message, you can be reasonably confident the message reached the server. If the client is on an unreliable network sometimes TCP connections do silently break, and it is a while before this is detected and they are closed. Possible solutions to this (in order of complexity):

- Ping the server at regular intervals using [XEP-0199](http://xmpp.org/extensions/xep-0199.html).
- Implement [XEP-0198](http://xmpp.org/extensions/xep-0198.html). Ultimate reliability, but more tricky to implement and requires server support.

The other issue you seem to be worried about is user2 seeing the message. I don't know about your application, how it is configured or how you want it to work. However most XMPP servers will automatically store messages sent to a user while they are offline. They are then delivered to the user when they come online. See [XEP-0160](http://xmpp.org/extensions/xep-0160.html) for more information.

Finally, you can use message receipts to know when user2 has received/read the message. These are described in [XEP-0184](http://xmpp.org/extensions/xep-0184.html), and are possibly the *only* thing you really need to implement if all you care about is knowing that user2 received the message.

Comment: Hey MattJ, all of what you talked about is implemented. I am not worried about the second user. I just want to know whenever the message that i send reaches the server or not. How to make the server reply to the sender that the message has arrived? Thanks

Comment: If you say everything I said is already implemented then you have XEP-0198, and that already gives you that information. Just send <r> after you send the message and the server will respond with <a> when it has received it.

Answer (score -1):

you need to implement ACK/NACK notification in your code.

Comment: Thanks for your response, how to implement that ACK/NACK in my code? I read that this should be dine in the description but how? Btw you mean the client code right?

Comment: well when you sent any message to server, the server should response "1" in case of successive reaching message from client to server. so this "1" is ACK for Client. and if client is not receiving "1" for a particular time then your client should resend the message

Comment: Well the server isn't responding anything that's why i am asking this question. For more information, I am using openfire server, are you sure about this info? Cause i tested it hundred of times and the server is not replying

Comment: ok tell me how you are sending code to server ? I am 100% sure that whenever server gets the message,it must return the code, atleast you must be getting 200 as response code which one type of ACK for you.

Comment: and there is no response like 200 because we are just using writer.flush method which will even not return an exception sometimes even if no internet connection is present

Comment: This is an existing and well documented protocol.  You cannot simply get a ack from the server, nor should you expect one when sending a messages.  IQ packets will ack, as that is part of the protocol, but simple chat messages do not as they require no response.  @MattJ has a good writeup which includes your options within XMPP.